# Perform some actions on tab switching

Tags: eclipse, swt

I'm using a CTabFolder to let the user edit a group of elements.

However, there is some data-dependency between some tabs (CTabItems) which requires me to re-load the content of a tab when its content is shown. (How) Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach a `SelectionListener` to the `CTabFolder` and exchange the control of your `CTabItem` there.

Let's assume you want to exchange the content of the second tab when the user selects it:

```
        folder.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent arg0) {
            if (folder.getSelectionIndex() == 1) {
                Text text = new Text(folder, SWT.MULTI);
                text.setText("foobar");
                folder.getItem(1).setControl(text);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Instead of using the selectionIndex, I verify if the current tab is the interested one: if(tabFolder.getSelection() == myTab) { ... }